# Logo display issue on safari ONLY

Tags: image, styles, responsive-design

I am creating a website which has the following code in it.

```
<style>
.browser_logo{
width:100%;
}
</style>
<img class="ie_logo browser_logo" src="images/clientimages/logo/logo.gif">
```

The image is about 1000px width which is extreme but it needs to be. The problem is that it is only 52px width in Safari. It is correctly displaying in Chrome, Firefox, Opera and even in IE. I have been looking the entire evening for Safari hacks but everything I find also changes the output in the Chrome browser. When I remove the width 100% or basically the style part then it shows the entire image as it should in safari. But then it will no longer be responsive. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have added the following to the style part above. Which makes it work but it is an ugly hack so I still would like to know how to do it properly.

This is the new code. I have used the screensizes from http://www.websitedimensions.com/

```
<style>
@media screen and (min-width:310px) {.browser_logo{min-width:310px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:468px) {.browser_logo{min-width:468px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:750px) {.browser_logo{min-width:750px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:989px) {.browser_logo{min-width:989px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:1010px) {.browser_logo{min-width:1010px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:1117px) {.browser_logo{min-width:1117px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:1245px) {.browser_logo{min-width:1245px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:1405px) {.browser_logo{min-width:1405px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:1645px) {.browser_logo{min-width:1645px;}}
@media screen and (min-width:1885px) {.browser_logo{min-width:1885px;}}
}
</style>
<img class="ie_logo browser_logo" src="images/clientimages/logo/logo.gif">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set `.browser_logo { width:100%; }` instead of using all of those media queries?

Perhaps it would be easier to understand what you were trying to do if you put it in a jsfiddle, or showed us the live link?

Comment: When i do what you say the picture will be in safari 50px width. So basically you are telling me exactly the same thing that i write in the first 5 lines of my question???

Comment: Can you stick a link to the project? Or pop it into a codepen/jsfiddle so we can take a look. (Or even just sketch out something in paint so we can get an idea of what you're looking for); I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do.